# Where can I read how to make web notifiers such as the StackExchange at the top left side of StackOverflow screen?

Tags: notifications

I'm not even sure what the name of that is to be able to make a search... but I would like to make those kind of things. Facebook has that too with the messages, notifications and friends requests. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you expect anyone to give you a complete tutorial with source code included? :) **You** should probably do some digging around yourself, since a concrete answer on this could mean to write a few pages :)
How can you dig around?
Thé tool for a job like that is ***[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug)*** (IMO).

With *bigger* tasks like these it makes sense to try to split it up in smaller pieces.
Let's say you go for a widget like the user profile popup on SO.

1. you need *some HTML* to display in a popup: right click on any html element on the popup and click the 'inspect element' menu item. This brings you to the HTML tab in firebug. This allows you to figure out how the HTML is structured
2. you need *some CSS* to style that popup: when you're *browsing* the html structure, you might already have noticed that on the right side of it is the CSS that is applied to the active element
3. you might want to use some animation effects: for that you could use jquery. Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to find out more on which effects are available and how they can be triggered. [Fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) is used in the profile popup on SO.
4. then you might ask yourself the question where SO get's that html structure from, right? To find out more about which server calls are made you can use the 'NET' tab in Firebug. (When you hover over your user name (only the first time?), then you should notice there's a call made to something like: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats?_=someLongNumberHere`
   In firebug you can then inspect the request and response. You should notice that the response is some HTML structure. This HTML structure is then inserted into the DOM.

Sooooo you can kinda glue it all together now:

- the user hovers over his user name
- the hovering [triggers](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) a server call (see step 4): use jquery [*hover*](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to attach a handler to the user link. (subsequent hovers don't trigger that server call, so there needs to be a check to see if that profile popup was already loaded or not)
- when the server call successfully returns (see [jquery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)), the returned html is [inserted](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) into the DOM and a fadeIn effect is triggered.
- it seems a mouseout is used to fadeOut the popup

I HOPE this is the answer you were looking for. It took me a while ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check out [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/)

Comment: What's the name for that kind of buttons?, like the search box that erases "search" on click is named Placeholder

Comment: it depends on the framework.... and the context, I suppose you're talking about adding a widget

Comment: I tend to call that a notifier, because it notifies the user of 'something new'. Widget is a very broad term.

Comment: A widget can be a notified, generally it is a block of code you drop into page somewhere, the functionality doesn't change the fact that its a widget, and if he didn't go straight to the api, I assume that is what he's looking for

Comment: @TweeZz @trey well, I want to begin with the visual issues, how to drop down a little menu on click; then I would like to go ahead with the server communications. I think that for the first, I would need to know what to do in CSS and HTML, but that's only a guess. Other example of that kind of things is the user name at the top of the screen that when the mouse is over it, shows information of your reputation information. I would like to begin writing an example that shows static content.